# How to create a Work Area during WIn Forms Design

Tags: c#, forms, textarea

How can i create a work Area in Win Forms?

My Design go like this:
 I have a Set of buttons aligned on the right side where each buttons opens up another form to either fetch or submit data to my backend. Now i need that when i click on the button from Form1(Having all the Buttons) then in my work area i should get other Forms.

I tried MDI Container, it solves the issue to some extent but then the problem comes up when the form load initially the container part is fully blank which looks bad from User Experience point of view.

Request you to please guide me or help me on how to proceed with the same.

Regards
Vineet More

Comment: *Working area* - means you want MDI. Can you post a specific problem code (don't forget to to google for it first!)? *Blank* working area can be easily solved by opening some window by default or, better, saving layout / restoring on next application start. Other then MDI option is to use windows desktop itself as a working area.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use MDI. Even Microsoft on msdn.com 'strongly suggests' not to use it!

Use TDI instead with panels and tab controls.

Have a look at this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.aspx

And this: 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269/A-multi-document-tabbed-interface